# Запись радиоэфира с пропуском тишины в Linux

Tags: linux, аудио

Доброго времени суток. Имеется трансивер, подключённый к линейному входу ПК под управлением убунты. Задача - вести запись вызывной частоты. Подскажите, какой программой можно захватывать линейный вход с пропуском тишины так, чтобы записи сохранялись в разные файлы с названием равным времени, в которое была сделана запись. Ещё лучше, если есть возможность писать всё в один файл, если тишина длилась, например, не более минуты. (Чтобы в один файл попадал, например, общий вызов и все отклики на него. А как только тишина длится более минуты - то следующая запись пойдёт в новый файл.)

Comment: распознавать тишину умеет, например, программа sox: google://sox+silence+detection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

есть программа streamripper

которой я записывал потоковое радио. Может писать в один файл. Может не записывать тишину.